# xml error in MTurk API request

Tags: html, xml, r, mechanicalturk

I am trying to create a Mechanical Turk Hit using R via API. I would like to create the HIT using an underlying html file and use therefore in my code the GenerateHTMLQuestion command. As far as I understood (I am a beginner), this command converts the html file into a XML file. Unfortunately the command always leads to the following error.

error: 1: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
2: Extra content at the end of the document

The html code is as following:

```
    <h3>Find the Website Address for this Retailer</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>For this retailer below, enter the website address for the official website of the retailer</li>
        <li>Include the full address, e.g. http://www.thecheesecakefactory.com</li>
        <li>Do not include URLs to city guides and listings like Citysearch.</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <p>Restaurant Name: <b>Teststrasse</b></p>
    <p>Address: <b>1</b></p>
    <p>Phone Number: <b>651351069</b></p>
    <p>Website Address:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="Q1Url" id="Q1Url" size="100" /></p>
    <p><style type="text/css">
    <!--
    .highlight-box { border:solid 0px #98BE10; background:#FCF9CE; color:#222222; padding:4px; text-align:left; font-size: smaller;}
    -->

</style></p>
```

I would very appreciate any help!

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used html questions directly, but it looks like your html code must be valid html5. (more info in the [mturk docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_HTMLQuestionArticle.html).)

From the docs, turk is not turning your html into xml, rather loading your html in an iframe. So the html must be a complete, valid html page.